# Merging two Fluttery projects

Tags: flutter

Hello I just started Flutter and ran into a problem
I have two Flutter programs, I wanted the second project to run when a button is clicked, please help me

I tried to do this and ran into the following problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oElkx.png)

Comment: Can You update your question with some example code?